# Vertically center TextView inside layout in android and also keep layout scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to vertically center the *TextView* in below layout with id *text_no_items* and also keep the layout scrollable in case the *TextView* with id *description* is very long and we need to scroll to see full content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This is a sample description about the items you will see below. This text could be very long."
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_no_items"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No items"
        android:textSize="48sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

The *TextView* is vertically centered if we set the height of parent layout (*LinearLayout*) to be *match_parent* and give layout weights as below. But in this case the layout is not scrollable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This is a sample description about the items you will see below. This text could be very long."
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_no_items"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No items"
        android:textSize="48sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Suggestions for using other layouts are welcome.

---

update: adding reference image. sorry for bad image quality
[image]

Comment: Can I ask you to include a picture of what's happening and maybe provide more information. Thank you, just so I know exactly what's happening so we know what we have to fix.

Comment: @TomasMota I have added image for reference

Comment: Do you mean that it's vertically centerd in the available space below the description textView?

Comment: @Zain yes, in the available free space.

Comment: @MohitYadav Thanks for clarifying, I posted an answer; please have a look; hopefully it works with you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ConstraintLayout` and put the description TextView inside `NestedScrollView` like the example below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/sample_text"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_no_items"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No items"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Update**

Use `ScrollView` as root layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/sample_text"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text_no_items"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_no_items"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="No items"
            android:textSize="48sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/description" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

This is the [content](https://loremipsum.io/generator/?n=5&t=p) of the `description` TextView.

Comment: It vertically centers the 'no items' text over the whole screen, instead it should be centred in the available space below the description text as shown in attached image. Also, this layout is not scrollable for some reason when used as Preference layout.

Comment: In the updated version, the no_items text is not vertically centred.

Comment: Have you Implemented it? @MohitYadav

Comment: I am currently using getListView().getViewTreeObserver()addOnGlobalLayoutListener() > onGlobalLayout() to change layout height to WRAP_CONTENT and MATCH_PARENT based on if height of no_items text is 0 or >0.When textview height is 0, the textview is not present on current viewport, so need to make layout scrollable, so I'm changing layout height to WRAP_CONTENT.

Comment: After changing the height to `WRAP_CONTENT` did it work? @MohitYadav

Comment: Yes. When the screen is filled with text, then there is no need to make the text centred. So, we change the height to wrap_content. And we can listen to configuration changes with onCinfigurationChanged, so if the viewport height changes and we need to center the text, we set layout height to match_parent. But I'm not using this solution now because the UX requirements has changed for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConstraintLayout`:

**For the top `TextView`:**

- Use a 0-biased chained packed constraint to make it stick to the top.

```
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
```

- Enable height constraints to stick it to the top of the bottom `TextView`

```
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text_no_items"
```

**For the bottom `TextView`:**

- Constraint the height with `0dp` & top to the top `TextView`, the bottom to the parent

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/description"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

- Set a minimum height to `wrap` so that the top `TextView` can't be greedy and push it off the bottom part of the screen.

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_min="wrap"
```

Here is the entire layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This is a sample description about the items you will see below. This text could be very long."
        android:textSize="32sp"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text_no_items"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_no_items"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No items"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/description" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the efforts but for my requirement, the 'No items' text needed not be sticky and floating over the other text at bottom. Now, I'm no longer looking for solutions for my question.